# stats.js shows FPS 0~2, render movement too slow

Tags: vue.js, three.js, frame-rate, gltf, bim

i'm beginner for three.js also using it for **BIM** project, 
when i load a **gltf** file of ~**25mb** i can barely move the whole object and stats.js monitor shows fps of 0~2 at max
gltf file : https://github.com/xeolabs/xeogl/tree/master/examples/models/gltf/schependomlaan
im using **THREE js** with **vuejs**

```
//package.json
"stats.js": "^0.17.0",
"three": "^0.109.0",
```

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

this.stats = new Stats();
this.stats.showPanel( 0, 1, 2 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
let div = document.createElement('div')
div.appendChild(this.stats.dom)

div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = 0;
div.style.left = 0;
document.getElementsByClassName('gltfViewer')[0].appendChild( div );
// Camera 
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500 );
this.camera.position.set( this.pos, this.pos, this.pos );
// renderer
this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.getElementById('gltfViewerCanvas'), alpha: false });
this.renderer.setClearColor( 0xefefef );
this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
// adding controls

this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.1;
this.controls.rotateSpeed = 0.12;
this.controls.enableDamping = true;
this.controls.update();

window.addEventListener('resize', _ => this.render());
this.controls.addEventListener('change', _ => this.render());

// light
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc );
this.scene.add( ambientLight );

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
this.scene.add( directionalLight );
// loading gltf file

// Instantiate a loader
this.gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

// Optional: Provide a DRACOLoader instance to decode compressed mesh data
this.dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
this.dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( 'three/examples/js/libs/draco' );
this.gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader( this.dracoLoader );

// Load a glTF resource
this.gltfLoader.load( this.src, this.onGLTFLoaded, this.onGLTFLoading, this.onGLTFLoadingError );
//onGLTFLoaded()
this.scene.add( optimizedGltf.scene );
// gltf.scene.getObjectById(404).visible = false;
this.listGltfObjects(gltf);

this.render();
// render ()

this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
this.stats.update();
// on mounted component :
animate()
// animate() 
this.stats.begin()
this.render();
this.stats.end();
```

even after applying Draco compression using https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline nothing changes.

Thanks

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', _ => this.render());
this.controls.addEventListener('change', _ => this.render());` you don't want this. You are forcing a out of sync render whenever you resize the window or move camera. You don't need to force render here, just setup an animation loop and it should make things significantly faster. [three.js basic scene guide](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)

Comment: After trying that it did go up to 1~4 fps :/ not to much

Comment: From the snippet provided I can't tell any other immediate thing that would cause this, just out of curiosity, could you edit your post with the code including the animation loop function and the function `this.render()` ?

Comment: Note that Draco compression reduces network size, but not the final amount of uncompressed data that must be sent to your GPU and rendered. If your original mesh was 100mb and you compress it to 25mb, you will still get the framerate of the original 100mb mesh. Aside: Using the `-b` option of glTF-Pipeline will reduce the size by another 50%, to 13MB, but again doesn't affect FPS.

Comment: Regarding performance: This model contains 4280 meshes, each requiring a GPU draw call. That is the source of your low QPS. You'll need to merge these meshes (in a program like Blender, or after loading in three.js) to as few as possible. A model like this should require < 100 draw calls, or even as few as 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*On filesize —*

Draco compression reduces network size, but not the final amount of uncompressed data that must be sent to your GPU and rendered. If your original mesh was 100mb and you compress it to 25mb, you will still get the framerate of the original 100mb mesh. Aside: Using the -b option of glTF-Pipeline will reduce the size by another 50%, to 13MB, but again doesn't affect FPS.

*On framerate —*

This model contains 4280 meshes<sup>1</sup>, each requiring a GPU draw call. That is the source of your low QPS, and unfortunately it's a common problem in BIM models. You'll need to merge these meshes (in a program like Blender, or after loading in three.js) to as few as possible. A model like this should require < 100 draw calls, or even as few as 1.

<sup>1</sup> To see this, try opening the model on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and opening the JavaScript console. You should see a printout of the scene graph, which will contain many different meshes.

Comment: Thank you for explain it to me, if i were to merge all meshes can i still manipulate each object alone ? like select a window and get it property for example ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. For that you might need to use something like `THREE.InstancedMesh`, which is a bit more work to set up but would allow you to move objects alone.

Comment: Thanks for explain it to me, if you may show me some **examples** or **tutorials** to **merge meshes** after threejs instancing objects ? i'm lost after testing too much example and it didn't work :/

Comment: @ElAlamiAnas Have you come around the issue? Could you share your code or experience?

Comment: If you can get the model into glTF format, then the [gltfpack](https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer#installing-gltfpack) tool can help you optimize it.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV hi and sorry for being late but the code in my question is what i did, also about the probleme it was an IFC model that has over 12k meshes that what caused the issue, Thanks